# Event handling - Visual Studio

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2013, event-handling

I am having issue as described below.  I am new to .NET/Visual Studio (2013) and I am trying to figure out why code below wont work.

I have following class

```
public class PropertySettings
{
    ...

    // get single instance of this class
    public static PropertySettings Instance
    {
        get { return thisInstance; }
    }

    // event declaration
    public event EventHandler<MyObj> PropertyChanged;

    ...

    public void SaveProperty(string propertyName, object obj)
    {
        var oldValue = obj.OldVal;
        var newValue = obj.NewVal;

        // Why is PropertyChanged event always null?
        if (PropertyChanged != null && oldValue != newValue)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, obj); // pass reference to itself
        }
    }
}
```

The SaveProperty method is checking that PropertyChanged != null and if so, it calls it by passing a reference to itself and obj.

Then the SaveProperty method is called from some other class like this:

```
PropertySettings.Instance.SaveProperty("Width", Width);
```

The problem I am having is that the PropertyChanged is always null so PropertyChanged event is never called.

Comment: Where do you wire up the PropertyChanged event handler?

Comment: Has anything subscribed to `PropertyChanged`?  It won't have a value unless it has at least one subscriber.

Comment: Crystal ball says that you should make the constructor of this class *private*.  Now the compiler tells you what you did wrong.

Comment: @dustmouse and rotyap.  Thank you for replying.  I am new to this so I am trying to figure out the very basics such as how to find if anything has subscribed to PropertyChanged?  How it is wired?  How do I check for that?  When I search for PropertyChanged in my whole project, I dont see any reference to it anywhere else other than in class I showed above.  Thanks,

Comment: To expand on @dustmouse. Somewhere in your code you need `myObj. PropertyChanged += MyObjectsPropertyChangedHandler;`

Comment: @HansPassant Sorry but that is unrelated.  The c-tor is private, I have not provided whole code above, just what is related to the question which is about event wiring.  Thanks anyways

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have an instance of your class:

```
var x = new PropertySettings();
```

Then you need to "wire up" any event handlers like this:

```
// "wire up" AKA "subscribe to" AKA "register" event handler.
x.PropertyChanged += HandlePropertyChanged;

// e.g. event handler...
void HandlePropertyChanged(object sender, object e)
{
    throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

Otherwise, `PropertyChanged == null` will be `true`.

Comment: That is very helpful, thanks.  My class above is a singleton as you can see and its method to save setting is called as described above.  So, I guess your suggestion to "wire up/subscribe/register" the event handler should be added somewhere in PropertySettings class?  Is that correct and if so where?  Much appreciated.

Comment: Sure.  Anywhere you want.  I'll leave that up to you.

Comment: Much appreciate roryap